# Issue with xbindkeys on xubuntu

Tags: xbindkeys

This code on `xbindkeysrc` file works fine:

```
"firefox"
m:0x18 + c:112
```

But this one, doesn't:

```
"xte 'keydown Control_L' 'key Tab' 'keyup Control_L' "
m:0x18 + c:112
```

Apparently, commands that use `xte` or `xdotools` aren't working for some reason.

All I want is a shortcut to switch browser's tabs from a combination of mouse buttons